# React `this.props` is undefined in user-defined function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using react.js and redux-form.
The component named LoginForm is a redux-form.
When I submit on the redux-form, the callBack function `loginRequest` will be executed. I will post the login message to the backend.

I am facing a problem.
I use the `connect` decorate to connect redux and react. 
In the function loginRequest. `this.props` is undefined,but in the `render` function render, `this.props.postLogin` is defined.

```
export default class Login extends  React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  loginRequest = (values) => {
    this.props.postLogin(values.username, values.password);
  }

  changeAllFun = () => {
    hashHistory.push('/organizationManager')
  }

  //organizationManager
  render(){
    return (
        <div style={style.loginStyle}>
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <RaisedButton disableTouchRipple={true}
                        disabled={false} label="postLogin"
                        onTouchTap={this.changeAllFun}
                        ></RaisedButton>
          <LoginForm onSubmit={this.loginRequest} style={style.loginStyle}/>    
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know the best practices to solve this problem.

Comment: This is the ES6 binding context problem, <LoginForm onSubmit={this.loginRequest}... loginRequest use "this", so you must explicity bind onSubmit={this.loginRequest.bind(this} or add this statement to constructor

Comment: Can you show where `Login` component gets connected?  And how the `postLogin` prop is passed in? :)  Can you also post the full error message you are receiving?

Comment: @ThànhChungBùi This is *not* the binding problem,  the method `loginRequest` is an arrow function.

Comment: @DavinTryon Have you give it a try?

Comment: can you show the code of parent component from where you are passing the `postLogin function` ?

Comment: @MayankShukla  the redux store is passing the `postLogin function`.  onSubmit={this.loginRequest.bind(this)}   work well.

Comment: @jiexishede post that as an answer, so that if someone facing the same issue, will get the solution. As well as it will tell that you got the solution :)

Comment: @MayankShukla I don't know how to post the comment as an answer. Is the upper triangle?

Comment: @jiexishede simply add a new answer mentioning the line that you used instead of arrow function :)

Comment: @DavinTryon Can you write the detail of your comment in the answer area? I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. The `this` is undefined When I inspect the React code and use the breakpoint to debug the React code. 
When I press the login button, this.props.postLogin is executed.
My chrome tricked me.
It is maybe a bug of `React Developer Tools`.